# Use the chain rule to find the derivative of a multivariable function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

[image]

I know that $\frac{dg}{dt} = (2xy , x^2)$

Is $\frac{d}{dt} g(r(t))$ simply equal to $\frac{dg}{dt}$  evaluated at $r(t)$?

If so, how would I calculate this? $g(x,y)$ depends only on $x$ and $y$, and neither of these depend on $t$.

Comment: I suspect this is intended to mean $x=\sinh(t)$ and $y=t^2$, so they do depend on $t$

Comment: Ah, thank you! That makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dg}{dt} = \frac{dg}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{dg}{dy}\frac{yt}{dt} = 2xy(\cosh(t)) + 2tx^2 = 2t^2\sinh(t)\cosh(t) + 2t\sinh^2(t)$$